# Show WordPress Editor in Plugin Settings

Tags: wordpress

I want to show the user a WordPress Editor to be able to use media and text and etc like post editor and save it in the options table. Of course, I can't use `textarea` or `input` but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to just use this simple code:

```js
<?php wp_editor( $content , 'editor-id' ); ?>
```

Thanks for your votes by the way!